# clearing object with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript, but got into trouble.
Here is an example,

```
type personType = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

const [person, setPerson] = useState<personType>()

if(person) {
  console.log(person.name, person.age)
}
return <button onClick={() => setPerson({})}>Click me</button>
```

There is no meaning of this code, but the idea is this:
I declared a type which is personType in this case and attached it to useState to be able to read person.name & person.age.
After reading the values, I would like to clear the person object when I click the button but I got an error which is "Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'".

What I have tried:

```
type personType = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

const [person, setPerson] = useState<personType | {}>()

if(person) {
  console.log(person.name, person.age)
}
return <button onClick={() => setPerson({})}>Click me</button>
```

In this case, it shows an error "Property'name' does not exist on type '{}'"

How can I solve this? Do I have to write setPerson({name: '', age: 0}) everytime I want to clear the object? what if it has a lot of properties?

Comment: `useState<personType|null>()` and assign null when you want to "clear" it

Comment: Or you could `setPerson(undefined)`

Comment: @Spikatrix 
yours is working as well! thank you :))